# How to access to new state of useReducer inside custom hook's function

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, use-reducer

I have a custom hook that uses `useReducer`.

```
function useMyCustomHook() {
   const [state, dispatch] = useReducer(EntityReducer, initialState);

   // console.log(state); // 1- state is up to date here

   const customDispatch = (action) => {
       dispatch({ ...action }); // first call EntityReducer by action.type

       //2- I use state and dispatch here(for example:use state for call an api, then dispatch response)
       // but the state is previous not new state?

       switch (action.type) {
           case "something":
               // use dispatch and state here                     
               return state;
       }
   }

   return [state, customDispatch];
}
```

use custom hook:

```
function HomePage(props) {
    const [state, dispatch] = useMyCustomHook();

    // for example use dispatch on click a button

    return (<div>...</div>)
}
```

Problem: the `state` is prev state inside `customDispatch`. How can I fix this?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As far as I realized your state staled in react-hooks(captured by closure).

Then you have these solutions:

1-`useEffect` with dependencies

```
useEffect(() => {
 // state will be updated here
 // declare 'customDispatch' here
}, [state,...]);
```

2-`useRef` inside `useMyCustomHook` like:

```
const [state, dispatch] = useReducer(EntityReducer, initialState);
const stateRef=useRef(state);

useEffect(() => {
        stateRef.current=state;
});

const customDispatch = (action) => {
// use state.current instead of state(state.current will be updated)
}
```